# embed bokeh chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, bokeh

I am trying to dynamically embed a bokeh chart on my webpage. I am using from bokeh.embed import components to give me a script & div components to embed into my page. However I can't work out how to add the script to my page. Below is the javascript I am using, I can see it being added on the page but as a string and it doesn't do anything.

**javascript**

```
  add_chart(div, script) {
    let ele = document.createElement('div');
    ele.innerHTML = div;
    document.getElementById('my_ele').appendChild(ele);

    let scp = document.createElement('script');
    scp.type = script;
    //scp.setAttribute('type', script);
    document.body.appendChild(scp);
}
```

**The script component**

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
  const fn = function() {
Bokeh.safely(function() {
  (function(root) {
    function embed_document(root) {
    const docs_json = '{"28b69ac1-333a-4628-a3f8-8b816b38d636":{"version":"3.2.0","title":"Bokeh Application","roots":{"p1131":"df455907-9e51-4ef2-9f1a-696441204478"},"root_ids":["p1131"]}];



   ... lots of lines...




    root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
    }
    if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
      embed_document(root);
    } else {
      let attempts = 0;
      const timer = setInterval(function(root) {
        if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          embed_document(root);
        } else {
          attempts++;
          if (attempts > 100) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
          }
        }
      }, 10, root)
    }
  })(window);
});
 };
 if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
 else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
})();
</script>
```